# Multiple instances of "add another photo" button - show div

Tags: javascript

I have a div that contains a file uploader. Next to this, there is an 'Add Photo' button.
This button once clicked should be hidden, and then reveal another file uploader div with another 'Add Photo' button, which will in turn hide/reveal another button & div upon click.

Anyone able to help? Apparently I cannot just copy the JS and repeat it to affect other ID's

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btnhide');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  btn.style.display = 'none';

  // ️ show div
  const box = document.getElementById('myDIV1');
  box.style.display = 'block';
});
```

```html
<div  class="form-content block"> 
        <div class="one">
            <label>Photo Upload <em class="tooltip">*<span class="tooltiptext">Required</span></em></label>
        </div>
    <div class="two">
            <input type="file" name="FileUpload" checktype="c1">
<p id="FileUpload_error" style="display: none;">Choose any file for this field.</p>
      <p>Please make sure each photo is 20MB or less, thank you. <button id="btnhide" type="button">Add Photo</button></p>
    </div></div>
  



  <div  class="form-content block" id="myDIV1" style="display:none;"> 
        <div class="one">
            <label>Photo Upload <em class="tooltip">*<span class="tooltiptext">Required</span></em></label>
        </div>
    <div class="two">
            <input type="file" name="FileUpload1" checktype="c1">
<p id="FileUpload_error1" style="display: none;">Choose any file for this field.</p>
      <p>Please make sure each photo is 20MB or less, thank you. <button id="btnhide1" type="button">Add Photo</button></p>
    </div></div>
  

  
  
   <div class="form-content block" id="myDIV2" style="display:none;"> 
        <div class="one">
            <label>Photo Upload</label>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <input type="file" name="FileUpload2" checktype="c1">
<p id="FileUpload2_error" style="display:none;">Choose any file for this field.</p>
<p>Please make sure each photo is 20MB or less, thank you. <button id="btnhide2" type="button">Add Photo</button></p> 
     </div></div>
```

Comment: Don't already have the additional markup in your document. This would hard limit how many additional blocks can be "made". Instead, create those additional blocks dynamically by cloning a template content, and append it to the DOM. For the buttons, use a delegate listener so it works for dynamically added buttons as well.

Comment: "Apparently I cannot just copy the JS and repeat it to affect other ID's". You can, with some changes, BUT do you really only ever want to allow a maximum of 3 photos uploaded?

Comment: @connexo 100% agree. I did find info on how to clone divs, which would be a much cleaner solution. However, I am following the code that Zohoforms supplied me with, as I am too inexperienced to build from scratch. The code requires each file upload to have a unique input name and ID in order for the form to submit and send via email. I am mostly just modifying the CSS/HTML to display properly on my site, as the code they supplied me with is not responsive. This modification would only be a band-aid until I am able to learn more and build my own form. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles ^ comment above is a reply to you as well. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

From the question comments:

> I am following the [HTML] ... supplied ... as I am too inexperienced to
> build from scratch.

So...*without changing any HTML* provided in the question...

...use Javascript to add a click event listener to each "Add Photo" button, that when clicked will navigate to its parent photo upload div, get the *next* photo upload div, display that, and finally hide itself (button only):

```js
// get all buttons within divs having className "form-content button"
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("div.form-content button");

// interate over resulting button array
btns.forEach((btn, ii) => {

  // add a click event listener to each one
  btn.addEventListener("click", evt => {

    // navigate up to the parent "form-content block" div
    // then get the next sibling and assign to photoupload
    // DIV.form-content+block > DIV.two > P > BUTTON
    const photoupload = evt.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    
    // if the next sibling is also a "form-content block" div, i.e., this is not the last photoupload,
    // display the next "form-content block" div
    if ( "form-content block" === photoupload.className ) {
      photoupload.style.display = "block";
    }

    // hide this "Add Photo" button
    btn.style.display = "none";
  });
  
  // and hide last "Add Photo" button——to not perplex people
  if ( btns.length - 1 === ii ) { btn.style.display = "none"; }
});
```

```html
<div  class="form-content block"> 
        <div class="one">
            <label>Photo Upload <em class="tooltip">*<span class="tooltiptext">Required</span></em></label>
        </div>
    <div class="two">
            <input type="file" name="FileUpload" checktype="c1">
<p id="FileUpload_error" style="display: none;">Choose any file for this field.</p>
      <p>Please make sure each photo is 20MB or less, thank you. <button id="btnhide" type="button">Add Photo</button></p>
    </div></div>
  



  <div  class="form-content block" id="myDIV1" style="display:none;"> 
        <div class="one">
            <label>Photo Upload <em class="tooltip">*<span class="tooltiptext">Required</span></em></label>
        </div>
    <div class="two">
            <input type="file" name="FileUpload1" checktype="c1">
<p id="FileUpload_error1" style="display: none;">Choose any file for this field.</p>
      <p>Please make sure each photo is 20MB or less, thank you. <button id="btnhide1" type="button">Add Photo</button></p>
    </div></div>
  

  
  
   <div class="form-content block" id="myDIV2" style="display:none;"> 
        <div class="one">
            <label>Photo Upload</label>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
            <input type="file" name="FileUpload2" checktype="c1">
<p id="FileUpload2_error" style="display:none;">Choose any file for this field.</p>
<p>Please make sure each photo is 20MB or less, thank you. <button id="btnhide2" type="button">Add Photo</button></p> 
     </div></div>
```

Using Javascript functions and properties: [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach),
[`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode), [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling), and [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className).